# Python sum of values in dataset

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have this dataframe (ID is a string and Value a float):

```
ID              Value
1               0.0
1.1             0.0
1.2             0.0
1.2.1           27508.42
1.2.2           25861.82
1.3             0.0
1.3.1           0.0
1.3.1.1         0.0
1.3.1.2         0.0
1.3.1.3         30396.25
```

Whose structure works like this:

```
1
├── 1.1  
├── 1.2  
│   ├── 1.2.1  
│   └── 1.2.2  
└── 1.3  
    └── 1.3.1  
        ├── 1.3.1.1
        ├── 1.3.1.2    
        └── 1.3.1.3
```

And need for the value of the 'parent' node to be the sum of the leaves. So:

```
ID              Value
1               83766.489    (1.1 + 1.2 + 1.3)
1.1             0.0
1.2             53370.24     (1.2.1 + 1.2.2)
1.2.1           27508.42
1.2.2           25861.82
1.3             30396.25     (1.3.1)
1.3.1           30396.25     (1.3.1.1 + 1.3.1.2 + 1.3.1.3)
1.3.1.1         0.0
1.3.1.2         0.0
1.3.1.3         30396.25
```

How can I group the IDs? Using groupby wont work since all the IDs are unique. Should I change the structure of the dataframe to better reflect the logic of the schema?

Comment: What if, say, the row with ID=1 had a non-zero value?  Should that be included with the sum of the "children"?

Comment: You can tell if the value in row ID=X should be included in the sum of the row with ID=Y if Y is a prefix of X.

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes, if ID=1 had a non-zero value the sum would be = 1+1.1+1.2+1.3. Also thanks a lot, I will look into the prefix solution. I don't know how to upvote an answer/comment yet.

Comment: "I don't know how to upvote an answer/comment yet." Did you take the [tour]? Did you try looking for that information in the help center that is linked at the end of the tour? To save you the steps, that process will take you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution (assuming column `ID` is sorted):

```py
def counter(x):
    out = []
    for id_, v in zip(x.index, x):
        s = sum(
            v
            for a, v in out
            if a.startswith(id_) and id_.count(".") == a.count(".") - 1
        )
        out.append((id_, s + v))
    return [v for _, v in out]


print(df.set_index("ID")[::-1].apply(counter)[::-1].reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
        ID     Value
0        1  83766.49
1      1.1      0.00
2      1.2  53370.24
3    1.2.1  27508.42
4    1.2.2  25861.82
5      1.3  30396.25
6    1.3.1  30396.25
7  1.3.1.1      0.00
8  1.3.1.2      0.00
9  1.3.1.3  30396.25
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej! Yes it is sorted. I had a very similar idea after another comment suggested checking if the leave is a prefix, but your 'id_.count(".") == a.count(".") - 1' solved the last part of the puzzle (My code would double count). Much thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could find which IDs make up the "child ID" of each ID and then sum across these "child ID"s

```py
from itertools import tee
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
a, b = tee(df['ID'].values)
b = list(b)
for a_val in a:
    for b_val in b:
        if b_val.startswith(a_val):
            d[a_val].append(b_val)
d
for b_val in b:
    df.loc[df['ID'] == b_val, 'total'] = sum(df.loc[df['ID'].isin(d[b_val]), 'Value'])
print(df)
```

```
        ID     Value     total
0        1      0.00  83766.49
1      1.1      0.00      0.00
2      1.2      0.00  53370.24
3    1.2.1  27508.42  27508.42
4    1.2.2  25861.82  25861.82
5      1.3      0.00  30396.25
6    1.3.1      0.00  30396.25
7  1.3.1.1      0.00      0.00
8  1.3.1.2      0.00      0.00
9  1.3.1.3  30396.25  30396.25
```